# Inserting an array into a diagram

Tags: beamer, diagrams, matrices, arrays, sharelatex

Suppose I have a diagram of this form:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages,amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,color, graphicx, amsfonts, braket}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}


\[
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{matrix} e \\ \text{John} \\ j \end{matrix} &
\begin{pmatrix}
e \to e \to t      & e \\
\text{saw}         & \text{Mary}\\
\operatorname{saw} & m
\end{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{matrix}
t\\
\text{John saw Mary}\\
\operatorname{saw}(j, m)\\
\end{matrix}
\]

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Suppose I want to insert the following diagram where the first *e* is in the diagram above (at the top left hand corner of that diagram, or suppose I want to insert it at any place in the top row of the above diagram)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages,amsmath,amssymb,mathtools,color, graphicx, amsfonts, braket}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usetheme{Madrid} 
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}

\[
\begin{array}{c|c}
 A & B\\
  \hline
  A & B\\
  \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{C}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How can I do this? I tried to literally copy and paste the second diagram into the first diagram, but this produced the error 'bad math environment delimiter'.

Comment: Just replace the `e` with the part from `\begin{array}` to `\end{array}` (inclusive).

Comment: @CarLaTeX Done.

Answer (score 2):

You just paste the `array`:

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\[
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{matrix} e \\ \text{John} \\ j \end{matrix} &
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{array}{c|c}
 A & B\\
  \hline
  A & B\\
  \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{C}
  \end{array}
 \to e \to t      & e \\
\text{saw}         & \text{Mary}\\
\operatorname{saw} & m
\end{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{matrix}
t\\
\text{John saw Mary}\\
\operatorname{saw}(j, m)\\
\end{matrix}
\]

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]